# Login page says login is wrong

Tags: php, laravel

Im trying to make a login in laravel and it wont give me a succes login.

This is the code for my login:

```
public function login()
{
    $user = array(
        'email' => Input::get('email'),
        'password' => Hash::make(Input::get('password'))
    );

    if (Auth::attempt($user)) {
        return Redirect::to('showlogin');
    }
    else{
        return 'Wrong username/password';

    }
}
public function showlogin()
{

    return View::make('login');

}
```

It always gives me the message: "wrong username/password". It doesn't matter what I put in. When I put the right combination it gives me the message and when I give type in a wrong combination it gives me message as well.

**Routes:**

```
Route::get('admin', 'TestController@login');
Route::get('login', 'TestController@showlogin');
```

and the 2 views

**Login**:

```
@extends('layout')
@section('content')
        <h1>Login</h1>
        {{ Form::open(array('url' => 'admin', 'method' => 'get')) }}
        <div>
            {{ Form::label('email', 'E-mail:') }}
            {{ Form::text('email') }}
            {{ $errors->first('email') }}
        </div>


        <div>
            {{ Form::label('password', 'Password:')}}
            {{ Form::password('password')}}
            {{ $errors->first('password') }}
        </div>


        <div>
        {{ Form::submit('Login')}}
        </div>
        {{ Form::close()}}
@stop
```

**Admin:**

```
@extends('layout')

@section('content')
<h1>Admin page</h1>
@stop
```

What is going wrong here?

Comment: You don't need to hash the password when passing it to `attempt()`. Try without the `Hash::make()`

Comment: @lukasgeiter Now I get a weird error:"NotfoundHttpException" in \bootstrap\compiled.php whenever I type a right combination. This fixed my problem though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to hash the password when passing it to `attempt()`. Internally the method will use `Hash::check` which needs the plain password to compare check if it's correct. (Every hash created will be new because it's composed of a random salt)

Without hashing it should work:

```
$user = array(
    'email' => Input::get('email'),
    'password' => Input::get('password')
);
```

Comment: Do you know what's going wrong with "NotfoundHttpException"?

Comment: That's basically a 404 not found. What you probably want to do is either `Redirect::to('login')` or `Redirect::action('TestController@showLogin')`

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention that the functions are in the controller themselves. So I get an error when I try that. Route [TestController@showLogin] not defined

Comment: Ah so you just want to call the method? `return $this->showLogin()`

Answer (score 0):

```
$user = array(
    'email' => Input::get('email'),
    'password' => Hash::make(Input::get('password'))
);
```

In this part of the code, you need to change the key "email" to "username". As far as I know, the Laravel User authentication checks on username + password.

Also: hashing is when saving a pass in the database. You won't need to create a Hash here. The attempt-function does that for you.

Comment: That would be a security flaw if you can pass every column you want. But still: the hashing-part of my answer remains.

Comment: I mean if your column is `username` you pass `'username' => 'foo'` if it's `email` you pass `'email' => 'bar'`

Comment: Still a security flaw. You should not be able to choose another column then "username" and "password" when you choose for legacy authentication. That you insert the e-mailaddress as an username is not the problem. Anyway, that's something that the Laravel developper should fix.

Comment: I don't see why this should be a security flaw. The developer has control over what he passes to `attempt()` so he decides which column he wants to use as user "identifier"

Comment: @lukasgeiter Same I dont see this as a security flaw.